# what is the word to be used when describing your subordinate achievements

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

what is the apt word that is to be used to describe the enthusiasm to learn and involve in work.

> Completed the assigned work well within the time and also proactive in learning the subject.

Does the above statements make any sense, I would like to recommend his promotion also  please give suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend

***a quick study***:

"one that can speedily learn the essentials of something to be done

especially : a performer (as an actor, musician) with a gift for learning with remarkable speed new material (as lines, stage business, scores)"

([Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick%20study)

Comment: Quick study would be fine. But my intention was to show his capacity and recommend for a promotion